# What to do with the questions which answered by comments itself?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, unanswered-questions

There are a lot of questions which users post, and the answer is to that is as minimal as a comment, and are solved most of the time.

These questions still remains as *unanswered questions*. They somewhat falls into the *foolish questions* category.

Still I wonder what should anyone do with these kind of questions?

Comment: Now this falls into the same category.